# Smokeping Mixed Probe types in Target Template

Tags: curl, dns, ping, probe

I'm attempting to setup Smokeping for my home office to troubleshoot some connectivity issues I've seen lately. Ideally I'd have a mix of FPing, DNS, and Curl monitors. The FPing probes work, however DNS and Curl doesn't populate and /var/log/messages says "No targets defined for probe X, skipping."

````
+ FPing

binary = /usr/bin/fping

+ DNS

binary = /usr/bin/dig
server = resolver.qwest.net
pings = 5
step = 120

+ Curl

binary = /usr/bin/curl
forks = 5
pings = 5
offset = 50%
timeout = 30

*** Targets ***

probe = FPing

menu = Top
title = Smokeping - Network Latency
remark = Home Office monitoring.

+ Ping

menu = Ping Monitoring
title = Ping Monitoring

++ LocalMachine

menu = Router (10.0.0.2)
title = Router (10.0.0.2)
host = 10.0.0.2
#alerts = someloss

++ SWCP

menu = members.swcp.com
title = members.swcp.com
host = members.swcp.com


+ DNS

probe = DNS

menu = DNS Monitoring
title = DNS Monitoring

++ Router

menu = Google
title = Google
lookup = www.google.com
server = resolver.qwest.net```
````